# Firebase Swift Crashes after updating photo

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am new to coding and firebase. I was able to get my image pickers to recall a photo but when the user updates it with an image picker, it causes the app to crash but it's able to update in my firebase database and firebase storage with the new photo.

Heres the code and the error message after updating the photo.

```
      func loadProfileImage() {

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("profileImageUrl").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    // Get download URL from snapshot
                    let downloadURL = snapshot.value as! String

                    // Create a storage reference from the URL
                    let storageRefPF = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: downloadURL)

                    // Download the data, assuming a max size of 1MB (you can change this as necessary)
                    storageRefPF.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data,error) -> Void in
                        // Create a UIImage, add it to the array

                     self.ProfileImageF.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                     print(snapshot)
                      //print(PIUvalue as Any)
                }
            })

    }
```

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I could really use the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason for crash:**

Your app is crashing because you are force unwrapping `data` in completion block. Force unwrapping `nil` value will crash your application.

More on this: 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/10/4/force-unwrapping & https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional

**Fix:**

Replace

```
self.ProfileImageF.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

With

```
if let imgData = data {
    self.ProfileImageF.image = UIImage(data: imgData)
}
```

This will fix your crash. If `data` is still `nil` and image doesn't show, I would recommend you to check firebase storage rules and make sure you have correct permissions.

Comment: Really appreciate it!